# Assigning String a value from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to assign a value from a cell in another workbook to a string variable in my code.

So currently my code will look up column P,G,H,I in the workbook but I have created another workbook which I have input all the columns I need it to look up. So on the other workbook I have mapped it out so the Ship to site ID value is P but I cant workout how to assign the value from this workbook to the below code.

I want it so I can just change the value in my mapping workbook rather than having to come back to my coding and change the column letter everytime there is a change.

```
ShipToSiteID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range("P" & counter))
AltShipTo1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range("G" & counter))
AltShipTo2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range("H" & counter))
AltShipToCity = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range("I" & counter))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Range("P" & counter)` this will be refering to the `ActiveWorksheet`

so it is the same as `ActiveWorksheet.Range("P" & counter)`

If you want to refer to another workbook then you need use a range from a sheet within this workbook.

```
Sub test()

Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
Dim newWorksheet As Worksheet

'NewWorkbook.xlsm is already open
Set newWorkbook = Workbooks("NewWorkbook.xlsm")
Set newWorksheet = newWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

MsgBox "This value is A1 in NewWorkbook - " & newWorksheet.Range("A1").Value

End Sub
```

You can also get an open workbook by index (although this isn't really recommended).

```
Set newWorkbook = Workbooks(1)
```

You can get and open a workbook at the same time by using `Workbook.Open`

```
Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:/Path/To/Workbook")
```

Or get and add a new workbook by using `Workbook.Add`

```
Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add()
```

---

Also, regarding your usage of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim`

There is a built in VBA `Trim()` function that would suit better..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure from your question how you are trying to copy from one workbook to another, but the below code is a general approach for getting a specific cell's data out of another workbook.

```vb
Sub GetOtherValues()
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet
    Dim thatWS As Worksheet
    Dim thatWB As Workbook
    Dim ShipToSiteID As String
    Dim counter As Integer

    Set thisWS = ActiveSheet
    Set thatWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\demo.xlsx")
    Set thatWS = thatWB.Worksheets(1)

    counter = 2 'initialized here for the sake of code completeness

    ShipToSiteID = Trim(thatWS.Range("P" & counter))

    'Do something else with the trimmed data from ShipToSiteID 
    thisWS.Cells(2, 2) = ShipToSiteID 

    thatWB.Close
End Sub
```

This code assumes you are running from the current workbook, and there is another worksheet/workbook that you need to get the data from.  After declaring the variables, it assigns `thisWB` to be the current worksheet, then opens the next workbook and assigns the first worksheet to `thatWS`.  We can now use `thatWS` and the `counter` variable to copy and trim the data, and stick it in the variable `ShipToSiteID` (and then do whatever else you're needing to do with it).

Comment: Hi, I am not trying to copy from one workbook to another. I am trying to copy the value from one workbook and put that value in my code. So my code is looking up a column .e.g. Column P. I have the value P in another workbook and I am trying to get it so it looks up this value. This way if any of the columns change instead of having to go in and change my coding and I change the value on the other workbook.

Comment: @user3581948 I updated my code per your comment.  I left in a reference to saving the data in the original worksheet, mostly because you don't state what you're doing with it after assigning it to the variable.